# Assign custom values to ID and FOR properties of the checkbox and label resulted from ngFor loop to populate list

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ngfor

My problem is two-fold:

1. I need to assign to each checkbox and label for checkbox unique ID and FOR value so each label corresponds to its according checkbox.
2. Finally I need to capture which fields have been checked (I'm thinking somehow in a map, key being the country and value true/false) and create an SQL query which I can then send to the backend to retrieve the filtered result.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for unique ID and FOR value.
[image]

And here is how I capture the checked items and use them in a query:
[image]

What I did was capture the check/uncheck and the name of the country in the countryNameAndCheckBoxStatus method inside the HTML component. Process these in an array inside the angular component and return the array so it can be processed further down the road into an sql query.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let country of countries$ | async">
  <input type="checkbox" [value]="country" id="cb-{{ country }}">
  <label for="cb-{{ country }}">{{ country }}</label>
</ng-container>
```

```js
  countries$ = this.powerPlantService.getPowerPlantCountryNames().pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

Comment: When I replce countries with getCountryNames() for some reason creates an endless loop in the browser console that takes up the whole processing power. Unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks, I have found a solution to my first problem and what your answer pertained to, and updated my question.